# event assignment using improper iterator value

Tags: javascript, closures

I am attempting to create a closure in a loop in order to set an event listener with my iterator value. However, the value in setCookie is not properly being set. What am I doing wrong here?

```
obj = document.getElementsByClassName("class");
l = obj.length;
i = 0;

function addEv() { 
    while (i < l) {
        obj[i].addEventListener("click", listener.bind(null, i));
        function listener(index) { 
            setCookie("item", index, 24) 
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for correcting :)

Answer (score -1):

**UPDATED ANSWER**

On way to capture iterating values is by using immediately invoked functions to capture the value in a closure.

```
while (i < l) {
  obj[i].addEventListener("click", (function(index) {
    return function(ev) {
      //setCookie("item", index, 24) 
      console.log(index)
    };
  }(i)));
  i++;
}
```

This example will wrap the iterating `i` as `index`.

Comment: Nothing is wrapped here. This only works because you're using the same name `i` for the two counter variables.

Comment: Bergi, thanks, working, but dont understand how, hahaha )))

Comment: @Bergi What do you mean? I only use the `i` for going through the `obj` array in the second loop. For each iteration in the second loop i call the functions inside the `obj`, which has stored all indexes with different values.

Comment: No, the functions in `obj` *don't* have stored any indices. Try to use `for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++) console.log(obj[j]());` instead and see it fail.

Comment: Sorry, you're completely correct! Will update answer.